# How can redirct a user to specific url based on his role in this react-redux code

Tags: node.js, reactjs, redux

I have node.js backend that has a login/signup and couple of urls that are accessed by their respective role. For example I have tested this url http://localhost:5000/api/deleteuser:user_id and this url is only accessed by a user that has role "ADMIN" and other routes with the same access control

in my react-redux application I managed to create login/register that uses jwt however after the user login with his username and password the system only direct him to the dashboard. i want to check the user role when the user attempt to login so that if he was admin then the system directs him to the admin page or if he is a teacher also to the teacher's page and so on.

at the moment i am struggling to figure how can I solve this problem.
i tried to used CASL for react but i just could not understand it so can you help me with this please

thanks in advance

I have tried to use CASL https://www.npmjs.com/package/@casl/react but I just could not understand it.

```
export const userSignin = (userData, history) => {
    return dispatch => {
        axios.post('/api/signin', userData)
            .then(res => {
                //success message
                toastr.success('Welcome')
                //redirect to dashboard



                //save token to location storage
                const { token } = res.data;
                localStorage.setItem('jwtToken', token);
                //set token to auth header
                setAuthToken(token);
                //decode token
                const jwtDecoded = jwtDecode(token);

                if(res.data.role === 'admin'){
                    history.push('/admin');
                }else{
                    history.push('/dashboard');
                }
                //set current user
                dispatch(setCurrentUser(jwtDecoded));
            })
            .catch(error => dispatch({
                type: GET_ERRORS,
                payload: error.response.data
            }))
    }
}

class Signin extends React.Component {
  state = {
    username: '',
    password: '',
    usernameError: '',
    passwordError: '',
    errors: {}
  }
  handleUsername = (e) => {
    this.setState({ username: e.target.value }, () => { this.validateUsername() });
  }
  handlePassword = (e) => {
    this.setState({ password: e.target.value }, () => { this.validatePassword() });
  }
  validateUsername = () => {
    const { username } = this.state;
    let usernameError;
    if (username === '') {
      usernameError = 'Username is required';
    }
    this.setState({ usernameError });
    return !usernameError;
  }
  validatePassword = () => {
    const { password } = this.state;
    let passwordError;
    if (password === '') {
      passwordError = 'Password is required';
    }
    this.setState({ passwordError });
    return !passwordError;
  }
  handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const validUsername = this.validateUsername();
    const validPassword = this.validatePassword();
    if (validUsername && validPassword) {
      const userData = {
        username: this.state.username,
        password: this.state.password
      }
      this.props.userSignin(userData, this.props.history);
    }
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    if (this.props.auth.isAuthenticated) {

      // const role = this.props.role;
      // if (role === "Admin") {
      //   this.props.history.push('/admin');
      // } else {
      //   this.props.history.push('/dashboard');
      // }

      this.props.history.push('/dashboard');
    }
  }
  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (nextProps.auth.isAuthenticated === true) {
      this.props.history.push('/dashboard');
    }
    if (nextProps.errors) {
      this.setState({ errors: nextProps.errors })
    }
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-4">
            {
              this.state.errors.success === false ? <p className="text-danger text-center">{this.state.errors.message}</p> : null
            }
          </div>
          <div className="col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-4">
            <h3 className='text-center'>Login</h3>
            <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
              <div className={classnames('form-group', { 'has-error': this.state.usernameError })}>
                <input
                  type="text"
                  className="form-control"
                  value={this.state.username}
                  onChange={this.handleUsername}
                  placeholder="Username"
                />
                <span className="help-block">{this.state.usernameError}</span>
              </div>
              <div className={classnames('form-group', { 'has-error': this.state.passwordError })}>
                <input
                  type="password"
                  className="form-control"
                  value={this.state.password}
                  onChange={this.handlePassword}
                  placeholder="Password"
                />
                <span className="help-block">{this.state.passwordError}</span>
              </div>
              <button className="btn btn-success btn-sm">Login</button>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
Signin.propTypes = {
  auth: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  userSignin: PropTypes.func.isRequired
}
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    auth: state.auth,
    errors: state.errors
  }
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps, { userSignin })(withRouter(Signin));


exports.signin = (req, res) => {
  User.findOne({ username: req.body.username }, function (err, user) {
    if (err) throw err;

    if (!user) {
      res.status(401).json({ success: false, message: 'Auth failed,User not found' });
    } else if (user) {
      var validPassword = user.comparePassword(req.body.password);
      if (!validPassword) {
        res.status(401).json({ success: false, message: 'Auth failed,wrong password' });
      } else {
        var token = jwt.sign({
          id: user._id,
          username: user.username,
          email: user.email,
          password: user.password,
          profileImage: user.profileImage,
          created_at: user.created_at
        }, config.secret, { expiresIn: '1h' });
        res.status(200).json({ success: true, message: 'Authenticated', token: 'Bearer ' + token });
      }
    }
  });
}
```

at the moment this only direct the user to dashboard, i think i am missing something here

Comment: what do you get when you `console.log(res.data.role)`?

Comment: the console.log(res.data.role) displays nothing 
the console shows nothing

shouldn't the res.data contains the user role?

Comment: what do you get when you `console.log(res)` and `console.log(res.data)`?  `res` contains whatever your API is returning.  It's best to log it out to be sure.

Comment: the console.log(res) gets me the response from the server with status 200 and a message from server says authenticated plus the token Bearer ....

now in the data i get the username and password, does that mean i have to change something in the server?

thanks

Comment: in the console.log(res.config.data) i get the username and password back from server however there is no role given back to me

Comment: sorry I just updated the code with server side login endpoint
starting from

exports.signin = (req, res) => {

Comment: I think it should return all the data from the user Schema but it only returns the username and password and I am not sure what i have missed here

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the last line of `exports.signin` you need to include the role in the object you're sending back.  for example you're sending this:

`res.status(200).json({ success: true, message: 'Authenticated', token: 'Bearer ' + token })`

but it needs to be something like this:

```
res.status(200).json({ success: true, message: 'Authenticated', role: 'admin',  token: 'Bearer ' + token })
```

Then in React, make sure you're accessing the correct element in that `if statement` to push to the proper route.

Comment: oh great, i never thought of this, thank you very much